# Printing comma-aligned doubles to printer device with Java

Tags: java, printing, alignment

For a project I need to print some numbers to the printer. They need to be printed below eachother, aligned on the comma. The font is not and can not be a monospaced one. I'm using a DecimalFormat("0.000") to transform all the numbers into strings ending in exactly 3 decimals.

What would be the correct way to align the numbers on the comma, below eachother? I'm using Java's Printable interface, as explained here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html.

Thanks

**EDIT: I'm not trying to print to the console, but to a printer (the actual hardware thing where real paper comes out)**

Answer (score 1):

This would certainly look better with a monospaced font.

I'm assuming that the comma is the decimal point.  Here's what I would do.

- Generate a comma image using drawString.
- Break up the number into two parts, the number before the decimal, and the number after the decimal.
- Generate the number images before the decimal and the number after the decimal using drawString.
- After all the numbers are converted to images, go through the numbers after the decimal images to see which one has the longest width.
- You now have the number of pixels of width for the longest numbers after the decimal, and the comma.
- Go through the number images again, drawing your images on the printer canvas in the following order.

  - Number after the decimal
  - Comma
  - Number before the decimal

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried to do something similar, splitting the number on the decimal point and printing the decimal part on a fixed point prefixed by a comma, and the prefixing the integer part. The problem is I can't figure out the anchor x for the integer part as it has variable length. I've tried `fontMetrics.charsWidth(...)` and throwing in the integer part of the number (as a string) as a parameter, but that doesn't work properly.  I think I'm just going to emulate a monospaced font by defining a charwidth and iterating over the string.toCharArray(). Thanks again!

Comment: On a sidenote, I'm having trouble making the printer print monospaced (on a different project...). Sure enough I'm setting the graphics environment's font to a monospaced font (`new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12)`) which is producing monospaced prints on Mac but not on Windows. Is this a printer manufacturer driver issue or can I do anything about it? I've also tried the Courier and Consolas fonts.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020978/monospaced-font-symbols-for-jtextpane

Comment: Thanks, this is more or less what I had though. I've tried setting the Font name to "Courier New" but I'm still struggling with it as now I don't get anything monospaced at all anymore, neither on Mac nor on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert them to aligned strings and then print these strings:

```
public static String align (String str)
{
    int n = str.indexOf('.');

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();
    for (int i = n; i < 3; i++)
        sb.append ((char)0x2007); // Append FIGURE-SPACE character
    sb.append (str);
    return sb.toString ();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random ();
    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.000");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        String str = format.format(Math.pow (r.nextDouble(), 3.0) * 150.0); 
        System.out.println(align (str));
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not printing to the console, I'm printing to a printer device using graphics.drawString(String str, int x, int y), and the string str is printed starting at location x, y from left to right (so left-aligned). The console is monospaced and that would be easy...

Comment: Even in non-monospace fonts, all digits usually have the same width, and there is special unicode character "FIGURE-SPACE" (U+2007) that has the same width as digits.